# How to access a method variable (Tkinter) from another method in same class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have defined some variables in method 1 and i call method 2 from it. In method 2, i have to access method 1 variable.

```
class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)               
        self.master = master
        self.myElements()

    def myElements(self):
        self.master.title("1841144-SANDRINE P JOY")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH , expand=1)
        label1=Label(text="Starts with").place(x=10,y=0)
        generateButton = Button(self,text="Generate", command=self.autogen)
        generateButton.place(x=150,y=0)
        label2=Label(text="--Here , your Random Name appears--").place(x=70,y=30)

    def autogen(self):
        randomName=pick(names)
        label2.insert(INSERT,randomName) #This line is wrong
```

Thanks @AKX & @Cool Cloud for figuring my errors

Here is the corrected code

creating an instance of a method of the variable was all needed for it

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)               
        self.master = master
        self.myElements()

    def myElements(self):
        self.master.title("1841144-SANDRINE P JOY")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH , expand=1)
        label1=Label(text="Starts with").place(x=10,y=0)
        generateButton = Button(self,text="Generate", command=self.autogen)
        generateButton.place(x=150,y=0)
        self.result=Text(self,width=10,height=1)
        self.result.place(x=70,y=30)
        mstart = Label(self, text="Starting with M",bg='white',fg='black',font=("italic", 10)).place(x=20,y=50)
        mtext = Text(self, width=15, height=10)
        mtext.place(x=10,y=70)

        pstart = Label(self, text="Starting with P",bg='white',fg='black',font=("italic", 10)).place(x=140,y=50)
        ptext = Text(self, width=15, height=10)
        ptext.place(x=120,y=70)

        nstart = Label(self, text="Starting with N",bg='white',fg='black',font=("italic", 10)).place(x=260,y=50)
        ntext = Text(self, width=15, height=10)
        ntext.place(x=240,y=70)     

    def autogen(self):
        randomName=pick(names)
        self.result.insert(INSERT,randomName)
```

Comment: The variable `label2` *ceases to exist* as soon as `myElements()` returns.  `autogen()` cannot possibly access it, because there's nothing to access.  Store it as an instance attribute, instead.

Comment: @jasonharper wouldnt saying `self.label2=Label(...)` and then `self.label2.insert(...)` work?

Comment: @CoolCloud no , it doesn't work

Comment: @SandrinJoy You have to say `self.label2 = Label(...)` then `self.label2.place(..)` then say `self.label2.insert(..)` but i believe `Label` does not have `insert()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them as instance variables (`self.label1` etc.):

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.myElements()

    def myElements(self):
        self.master.title("1841144-SANDRINE P JOY")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.label1 = Label(text="Starts with")
        self.label1.place(x=10, y=0)
        self.generateButton = Button(self, text="Generate", command=self.autogen)
        self.generateButton.place(x=150, y=0)
        self.label2 = Label(text="--Here , your Random Name appears--")
        self.label2.place(x=70, y=30)

    def autogen(self):
        randomName = pick(names)
        self.label2.insert(INSERT, randomName)
```

Comment: `self.label2` is `None` as it is the result of `Label(...).place(...)`.

Comment: return self.func(*args)
  File "nameGen.py", line 43, in autogen
    self.label2.insert(INSERT,randomName)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: @acw1668 yes , its NoneType

Comment: @SandrinJoy You have to say `self.label2 = Label(...)` then `self.label2.place(..)` then say `self.label2.insert(..)` but i believe `Label` does not have `insert()` method

Comment: Fixed the `.place()`s.

Comment: @AKX i still expect an error because i believe `Label` dont have `insert()` method

Comment: yes , i appended all with self. , still same error. But i understood why i get the error. its because , that variable is very local.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys , i fixed it. It was that label error